# Using parametrised values and 'Symbols' in Cirq

Tags: programming, cirq

I'm just wondering how one should go about using parametrised values and the Symbol object that gets resolved at runtime?

For example, if I would like to implement the gate
$R_x(\theta) = e^{-i\theta/2}$, but would like to leave $\theta$ as a Symbol to be resolved at the end of the simulation, what would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Answer (score 3):

In the current release of Cirq (0.4.0) there is a strong limitation on symbols: you can't scale them or add them (Why? We were worried about being pulled down the rabbit hole of implementing a whole symbolic algebra system.). Making matters worse, Cirq internally works in radians divided by pi to avoid some minor sources of floating point error. So when you write `cirq.Rx(cirq.Symbol("θ"))` it internally attempts to scale the argument, and you get an error about multiplication/division not being supported for symbols.

There is [an active pull request](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/pull/990) to fix this by delegating all symbolic work to sympy. Once that's merged, the next release will allow you to write `cirq.Rx(sympy.Symbol("θ"))` whereas currently you can only use symbols in exponents e.g. `cirq.X**cirq.Symbol("t")`.

So, currently in 0.4.0, you can do this:

```
import cirq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

q = cirq.LineQubit(0)
circuit = cirq.Circuit.from_ops(
    cirq.X(q)**cirq.Symbol('angle_over_pi'),
    cirq.measure(q),
)
results = cirq.Simulator().run_sweep(
    circuit,
    params=cirq.Linspace(key='angle_over_pi', start=0, stop=2, length=20),
    repetitions=1000)

plt.plot([r.histogram(key=str(q))[1] for r in results])
plt.show()
```

[image: rabi oscillation]

But you'll need to wait until 0.5.0 to be able to do this extremely similar thing using `Rx` instead of `X**` and `sympy.Symbol` instead of `cirq.Symbol` (which will be gone):

```
import cirq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

q = cirq.LineQubit(0)
circuit = cirq.Circuit.from_ops(
    cirq.Rx(sympy.Symbol('rads')).on(q),
    cirq.measure(q),
)
results = cirq.Simulator().run_sweep(
    circuit,
    params=cirq.Linspace(key='rads', start=0, stop=2*np.pi, length=20),
    repetitions=1000)

plt.plot([r.histogram(key=q)[1] for r in results])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, that clears everything up for me!